# WS to Service concern

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest

I have a **Rest** layer that call the **Service** layer.

My language is **Java** with Spring Framework

With some code would be:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Entity get(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    Entity entity = new Entity();
    entity.setId(id);
    return entityService.get(entity);
}
```

**Well.... here are my questions:**

1. Is it better to have a generic method in Service layer to hold the
   parameters and filter to get and etc?
2. Is it better to have unit methods to filter the get like:

   entityService.getByID(id);
   entityService.getByValue1(value1);
   entityService.getByIDAndValue1(id, value1);
3. Is it better to set the properties of Entity at Rest layer and call
   service passing an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have some separate methods for more frequent use cases, like `findByPrimaryKey(id)` or `findByName`, and also a find by example method that will find entity by all not null fields in given entity.

You can also define a Business aware query interface (i mean no database layer query) to find objects, But this will complicate your rest service layer code so i prefer separated and simple methods that will make your service layer more readable.

There is also a [Parameters Object](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074935/core-java/too-many-parameters-in-java-methods--part-2--parameters-object.html) design pattern, that mean grouping logically related parameters in object, eg. start date and and date as `DateRange` object.

But is useful when some logically related sequence of objects are passed as parameters to various methods. For example contact parameter may contain address, Zipcode and tel.

Comment: Thanks dude, I'll put a find method for generic searches